# Smoothness of polynomial algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit, and $A$ the algebra $R[X]/(f)$, where $f$ is a monic polynomial. We consider $\Omega_{A/R}$ the $A$-module of Kähler differentials.

Recall that we say that $A$ is smooth $R$-algebra of relative dimension $d$ if $\operatorname{dim} (A \otimes_R k) = d$ for all residue fields $k$ of $R$ and if $\Omega_{A/R}$ is locally free of rank $d$. (defined in terms of derivations, not with the augmentation ideal)

I want to find an equivalent condition on $f$ so that $A$ is smooth of relative dimension $0$.

I proved that $\Omega_{A/R} = \operatorname{coker} J \otimes_{R[X]} A$, where $J$ is the jacobian of $f$. I tried to prove some kind of jacobian criterion, but this only works for algebras over a field, and I'm sure there is an easier way to do it. My first draft was something like:

$\Omega_{A/R} = 0 \iff \operatorname{coker} J \otimes_{R[X]} A = 0 \iff \operatorname{Im} J = 0 \iff (df/dx) \in A^\times$,

but I am pretty sure the second "iff" is false, and this doesn't use the condition on the dimension over the residue field.

Comment: Why would you use this dimension condition for smoothness? This is not standard, compare eg with https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TZ, SGA I or Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud’s *Néron models*.

Comment: @Aphelli Well that was the definition I was given so I try to solve the problem using it.

Comment: The condition on the residue field is redundant, at least for relative dimension zero. Your final criterion is correct.